# How to change logo of print order PDF on success page

Tags: orders, pdf, print

I am unable to update the store logo on the pdf which get generated when order ia placed and a link to print order PDF is shown to user.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is pretty simple to change logo from Magento Admin.

Goto to the backend of your website:

1) Goto `System>>Configuration>>SALES>>Sales`

2) Open the tab Invoices and Packing Slip Design and change the logo from there.

[image]

Comment: This is still relevant configuration in Magento 2.